# What's the name of rays and faces in high dimensional spaces?

Tags: geometry

"Simplex" is the $n$-dimensional generalization of the $1$-dimensional *segment*, the $2$-dimensional *triangle*, and the $3$-dimensional *tetrahedron*.

"Hyperplane" is the generalization of the $0$-dimensional *dot* in $1$-dimensional space, the $1$-dimensional *line* in $2$-dimensional space, and the $2$-dimensional *plane* in $3$-dimensional space.

> Are there names for generalized *rays* and *faces*, i.e., parts of hyperplanes with one or more boundaries in $n$-dimensional space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- ["Half-space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_(geometry)) is the generalization of "ray" (aka, "half-line").
- For corner-like analogues of angles, I'm not sure of a particular name for arbitrary cases. However, ["orthant"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthant) is the generalization of the $2d$ "quadrant" and $3d$ "octant": a region bounded by $d$ mutually-perpendicular hyperplanes through a vertex (usually, the *coordinate* hyperplanes through the *origin*). Note that we can assign a ["solid angle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) measurement ---in ["steradians"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steradian)--- to corner-like regions, even if the boundary elements aren't "flat".
- For regions fully bounded by hyperplanes, the generalization of "point", "segment", "polygon", "polyhedron" is ["polytope"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope). A $d$-polytope is bounded by $(d-1)$-polytopes: *endpoints* of a *segment*; *edges* of a *polygon*; *faces* of a *polyhedron*. The generalization there is often "*facets* of a polytope", although "facet" is *also* used to describe [certain *non-face* elements of a polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facet_(geometry)), so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

One can generalize *ray* to *half-plane* and, in higher dimensions, to *half-space*.

Faces can be awkward. Different mathematical disciplines can use words such as *polyhedron*, *polytope*, *face*, *facet* and so on in different and sometimes incompatible ways. Typically the higher-dimensional generalization of a *face* will be either a *face* or a *facet* - terms such as *cell* or *hypercell* are also occasionally still used.